# Get modifiable TCHAR* from element of CStringArray

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, atl

Here is my attempt and error:

**code:**

```
 TCHAR* pszDisplayName_I; //$I .. file
 TCHAR *pDollar = NULL;
 pszDisplayName_I = ((CString)saSursa.GetAt(i)).GetBuffer();  
 pDollar = _tcsrchr(pszDisplayName_I,'$');  
 *(pDollar + 1) = 'I';
```

**error:**

```
 error C2248: 'CObject::CObject' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CObject' C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxcoll.h
```

for the getBuffter function I found this:

*Returns a pointer to the internal character buffer for the CString object. The returned LPTSTR is not const and thus allows direct modification of CString contents.* 
So it is ok.
But for the getAt(0) function it says this:

```
CObject* GetAt(
 INT_PTR nIndex 
) const;
```

So there it is, the **const thing**, is there a way around this? A way in which I might get a modifiable CString element from a CStringArray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just compiled this successfully. Instead using GetAt() I used the [] operator.

```
CStringArray saTest;
saTest.Add(_T("Test"));
TCHAR* pTest = saTest[0].GetBuffer();
saTest[0].ReleaseBuffer();
```